# Correcting the features added to stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote this code to put "insert and update" into a transaction and also I need to have a check constraints to avoid negative PersonalID finally I want to have error handling so that if a negative PersonalID is added it warns using C#. Would you please help me correct that, it is not working, logically there might be a problem beyond the syntaxes.

the errors : Incorrect syntax near 'Start'.

Incorrect syntax near 'Start'.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

```
com.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Facebook( @PostID int,@PersonalID int)
AS " + "Start Transaction INSERT dbo.[Like] (PostID) VALUES (@PersonalID) Commit; " +    
"Start Transaction UPDATE dbo.[Counter] SET Counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[Like]  
WHERE PostID = @PersonalID) Commit" + " FROM dbo.Counter AS C " + " WHERE C.PostID =  
@PersonalID , ADD CONSTRAINT NegativeValue CHECK (PersonalID >= 0 )";
```

Comment: Pretty sure check constraints only apply to columns in tables, not params to stored procedures.

Comment: Also it's `begin transaction` not `start transaction` for SQL Server.

Comment: @John : You are so true when u said it's begin transaction not start! but PersonalID being checked in my check constraint is a cloumn of my like table. it is not still working. any other suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your current SQL, and the specific error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in SQL Server is `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. The second `COMMIT` is premature because it is before the `FROM` clause. Put it at the end.

That solves the syntax errors but the explicit transactions are useless here anyway. In SQL-Server everything is executed in a transaction. If you do not specify any, you get an automatic transaction for each statement - exactly what you are doing here manually.

I'm confused by the semantics of your Stored Procedure. You never use the `@PostID` Parameter, you assign the value `@PersonalID` to the `PostID` column in the `Like` table and you compare `@PersonalID` to the `PostID` column in the `Counter` table.

Now, `CHECK CONSTRAINT`s cannot be specified on statements like `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and so on. They are part of the table definition, so you need to integrate it in the table definition or alter the existing table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Like] ADD CONSTRAINT Like_PostID_NonNegative CHECK (PostID >= 0)
```

No every time someone tries to insert a negative PostID-value into the `[Like]` table, SQL Server will throw an error.

The Stored Procedure would then look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Facebook (@PostID int)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.[Like] (PostID) VALUES (@PostID);
  UPDATE dbo.[Counter] 
    SET Counter = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                   FROM dbo.[Like]
                   WHERE PostID = @PostID)
    WHERE PostID = @PostID;
END;
```

By the way: If you put both statements into one transaction, you can remove the counting of all like-entries every time you update (which will get very slow for many likes) and just update the counter like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Facebook (@PostID int)
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT dbo.[Like] (PostID) VALUES (@PostID);
    UPDATE dbo.[Counter] 
      SET Counter = Counter+1
      WHERE PostID = @PostID;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

SQL Server guarantees to you that either both statements changes are stored or none of the changes (in case of an error).

Comment: Dear mate Toni, Would you please change the code to what you think will work correctly having the transaction? because i did modify it according to your tips but something somewhere is wrong.

Comment: @user3158098: Sorry, I didn't notice the constraint clause. I will update my answer shortly.